# OS X 10.6 Server .htaccess, WebDAV, and CakePHP trouble

Tags: apache, cakephp, webdav, osx-server

With CakePHP I really need .htaccess files working so I enabled mod_rewrite and quickly found out OS X's Apache configuration blocks uploading and reading of htaccess files over WebDAV. I fixed that in httpd.confg but hit ran into a wall.

Cake's structure has this .htaccess file in three primary locations (there are others but this is what matters right now) {, app, webroot}

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
   RewriteEngine on
   RewriteRule    ^$ app/webroot/    [L]
   RewriteRule    (.*) app/webroot/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

As soon as these files are copied into their place on the OSX server WebDAV stops working. I can no longer write to or read from the directories. I don't know much about mod_rewrite, but I'm guessing that I need to not apply rewrite rules if the requests are WebDAV. Any thoughts or fixes would be most helpful.

Comment: If you are having problems with the built-in Apache, can you build Apache, PHP & MySQL using something like Home Brew or Mac Ports instead? http://2tbsp.com/content/install_and_configure_mysql_5_macports

Answer (score 0):

I am working on this problem too, to fix the 3times of rewrite, i will just point my virtual host to the webroot directory instead.

here is the code i put in my httpd.conf

```
NameVirtualHost localhost:80
<VirtualHost localhost:80>
    DocumentRoot "/Users/yilliot/Sites"
</VirtualHost>
<VirtualHost cake.localhost:80>
    DocumentRoot "/Users/yilliot/Sites/demo/cakephp-1.3/app/webroot"
    <Directory /Users/yilliot/Sites/demo/cakephp-1.3>
        Options FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride All
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

This is a good start i believe it is.